# SocketException Broken pipe receives when the server is under load (Spring AMQP)

Tags: spring, amqp, spring-amqp

We are using Spring AMQP 2.8 with RabbitMQ 2.8.7 version. We are building our connection factory as below.

```
<!-- RabbitMQ Local connectivity -->
<rabbit:connection-factory
        id="localWhispirConnectionFactory"
        addresses="${system.local.rabbitmq.host}"
        username="${system.local.rabbitmq.username}"
        password="${system.local.rabbitmq.password}"
        connection-factory="rabbitWhispirLocalFactory"/>

<!-- Heartbeat configuration every 10sec -->
<bean id="rabbitWhispirLocalFactory" class="com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory">
    <property name="requestedHeartbeat" value="10" />
</bean>
```

But when the server is under load, we received the below exceptions. Tries several ways, but appreciate any comments to overcome this issue.

```
2015-04-20 12:01:00,174 INFO  [SimpleMessageListenerContainer] Restarting Consumer: tag=[amq.ctag-wfazQuIuS-BM-CosxP_2GJ], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://whispir@10.50.50.128:5672/,62), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2015-04-20 12:01:00,156 WARN  [SimpleMessageListenerContainer] Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
2015-04-20 12:01:00,174 INFO  [SimpleMessageListenerContainer] Restarting Consumer: tag=[amq.ctag-AjjxOJ2doe4yi2GtTHKumM], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://whispir@10.50.50.128:5672/,29), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such version (2.8) of Spring AMQP. Currently, the latest version is [1.4.4](http://projects.spring.io/spring-amqp/).

Check the server logs to see if there are any clues there.

That said, 2.8.7 is a very old broker; I am quite sure the rabbitmq guys would recommend upgrading to a more recent version, currently the latest is [3.5.1](https://www.rabbitmq.com/).